# What is on-topic and off-topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, beta-essentials

One of the essential components of the FAQ will be the list of on-topic and off-topic subjects for questions.

Following the model used at [this English L&U meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/what-is-on-topic-and-off-topic-here), let's use this question to vote on what topics should be on and off topic at Apple SE.

In other words, post answers that are of the form:

> **{On-topic}**
>
> One subject area you suggest to be considered on-topic

-- **or** --

> **{Off-topic}**
>
> One subject area you suggest to be considered off-topic

Then upvote and downvote any answers as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

**{On-topic}**

[Features of / problems with] Apple hardware and devices
(E.g. Mac Pro, iBook, iPod shuffle, Magic Trackpad)

Answer (score 2):

**{On-topic}**

End-user level problems/dilemmas with OS X

Answer (score 1):

**{Off-topic}**

Stock performance and financial outlook of Apple Inc.